# WordPress Theme not Enqueuing main.js Script - No Errors Displayed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
function turboweb_studio54_scripts() {
    // Avoid loading these resources in the admin area
    if (!is_admin()) {
        
        // CSS Enqueue
        
        // Load Bootstrap CSS first
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap-5.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '5.3.1');
        
        // Main theme styles, dependent on Bootstrap CSS
        wp_enqueue_style('turboweb-studio54-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap-css'), _S_VERSION);
        
        // Add right-to-left language support
        wp_style_add_data('turboweb-studio54-style', 'rtl', 'replace');
        
        // Navbar styles, dependent on the main theme styles
        wp_enqueue_style('turboweb-studio54-navbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/navbar.css', array('turboweb-studio54-style'), _S_VERSION);
        
        // Additional main styles, dependent on navbar styles
        wp_enqueue_style('turboweb-studio54-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array('turboweb-studio54-navbar'), _S_VERSION);
        
        // JS Enqueue
        
        // Load Bootstrap JS first, dependent on jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap-5.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), '5.3.1', true);
        
        // Theme navigation scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('turboweb-studio54-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true);
        
       // Main theme scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('turboweb-studio54-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true);
        
        // GSAP for animations, dependent on jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script('gsap-tweenmax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
        
        // Additional scripts for threaded comments, only if needed
        if (is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
            wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'turboweb_studio54_scripts', 100);
```

Steps Taken:

Checked if the main.js file exists in the specified path - it does.
Tried changing the order of enqueuing assets.
Renamed the main.js to tw-script.js thinking there might be a naming conflict, but the issue persists.
Tried using a higher priority (100) in the add_action for wp_enqueue_scripts but that didn't help.
Checked if there's a 404 error in the browser console for the main.js file, but there's none.

Comment: Welcome! Try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`. Are the rest of your scripts loading?

Comment: Looks like you have two different directories for JS files, `/js` and `/assets/js`, are they both correct?

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, it's not working. The rest of the scripts are loading correctly. (I tried renaming the file, as that would cause a 404 error in the console. However, this approach didn't work – there's no error, and the functionality remains unchanged.) @JarmoT both directories are correct, and I'm using underscores. Additionally, I'm working with a separate "js" directory, attempting to isolate custom functions from the existing theme.

Comment: UP* It seems that if I add its path in the footer it works, but not in the wp_enqueue function.

Comment: UP* Issue resolved, I forgot to include get_footer(); in the new homepage template. The scripts are loaded in the footer, but without "get_footer();" in the new template, they had no place to be loaded :)) Thank you for your attention and support, great community!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.